# What is a stochastic process in a physics context?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, randomness, stochastic-processes

In my mind, a [stochastic process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process) is simply a "random" process, one where the outcome is informed by initial conditions but *not in a deterministic way*.  Is this a correct definition?  What are some examples of stochastic processes in physics?

Comment: Stochastic process is a technical, mathematical, term (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process). Its uses in physics are many, in fact too many, making the question perhaps too broad to answer. Possibly the most important stochastic physical phenomenon is Brownian motion which is typically modeled through the Langevin equation.

Comment: This question (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: @alarge, I am just asking for some examples, not an exhaustive list.